# I would like to know how to disable cookies in Rails 5.1

Tags: cookies, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a small app which is used by company staff only.  I don't use any 'cookies/session' information from Rails directly.  Given current requirements to request acceptance for cookies etc.  I would like to completely disable cookies so that Rails doesn't send ANY cookies to the browser with any responses I generate.

Answer (score 24):

To disable cookies completely, use this inside application.rb:

```
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

and in config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :disabled
```

You can find more details at this blog post:
http://www.glitchwrks.com/2017/01/16/removing-cookies-sessions-rails-5

Btw, if you need to disable cookies only for some controllers/actions you can use this:

```
    after_action -> { request.session_options[:skip] = true }
```