# Rails 6 - Delete session without creating a new one. (Completely GONE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-6

On Ruby on Rails 6; I'm trying to remove the session cookie.  The cookie was needed for a short while to contain a flash message though a redirect and once the flash message is done, I want to remove the cookie completely.  No resets, I want the cookie gone.

I've tried

```
  session.clear
  session.destroy
  cookies.delete cookie_name.to_sym
```

Is there a way to delete the session cookie?

Comment: Which `config.session_store` are you using?

Comment: We store to Redis

Comment: So you store your session _data_ in Redis, but the session _id_ is still stored as a cookie, right? You have to store the _id_ somewhere. Are you going to put it in the URL instead, or in an HTTP header?

Comment: There are some interesting ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055984/i-would-like-to-know-how-to-disable-cookies-in-rails-5-1

Comment: Was the cookie was originally set with a `domain` option? If so, you may need to provide that domain as an option again when calling`cookies.delete`. (According to  the docs at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html )

Comment: @JaredBeck The session is empty the session id would be stored in the cookie, except I'm trying to remove the session cookie so that it does not come back .

in regards to 2nd comment, I still need cookies here and there.

Comment: @obiruby I added domain: (my domain).  Good catch, but it didn't work